# Why does Redux need Actions and Reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to understand why [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/) is designed the way it is.  For example suppose I have a store that contains a list of todos.

If the store is effectively an object like this:

```
{1: todo1,
 2: todo2,
 3: todo3, ...}*
```

And we wrap it in a class that allows us to do things like:

```
todoStore.getAll()
todoStore.add(todo)
todoStore.get(id);
todoStore.get([1,2,3,...]);
todoStore.filter((todo)=> todo.id == 1);
todoStore.del(1);
todoStore.update(2, {title: 'new title'}:Partial<Todo>);
....
```

So in this case all we have is a `Todo` model and a `TodoStore` that has an API that allows us to query / filter, delete, update, and add items.

Why does Redux need the Actions and the Reducers?

One of the answers indicate that:

> Instead Redux uses a pattern that, when given a state and action will always produce the same new state.

So it seems that because of this pattern we need actions and reducers, but to me these look like internal implementation details.  Why can't the `TodoStore` just implement these internally?

For example if we have 1 todo instance in the cache and we add another one, we now have 2.  This seems like a pretty simple thing to implement ... but I must be missing something ...

### Background

I was thinking about implementing something like

```
@TodoStore
class Todo {

}
```

The annotation / decorator would generate the store and clients would then get the store via something like:

```
todoStore:TodoStore = StoreCache.get(Todo);
todos:Observable<Todo[]> = todoStore.getAll();
...
```

Etc.  It seems like it could be this simple ... so just wondering what Redux provides that this might be missing ... In other words why did redux decide that it needed actions and reducers instead of a simple `Store<Type>` like interface?

Yet a different way of looking at it is do the Reducers and Actions add something that the `Store<Type>` interface cannot add via the way that is implemented / language constraints?

### Assertions

- The action is the method name combined with the entity name.  So for example if we have `Store<Todo>` (A Store type that operates on todo types), and say an update method such as `update(id:String, todo:Todo)`, then we effectively have the name of the Action which would be **TODO UPDATE**.  If the second argument were plural, so `update(id:String, todos:Todo[])`, then the action is **TODO UPDATES** ...
- If we are doing updates we have to find the instances that we are updating and update them, and we typically do this with an ID.  Once the updates are complete we can track them in an immutable state tree if we wish to do some, and for example the entire change could be wrapped in a command object instance so that we could undo / replay it.  I believe the Eclipe EMF framework API has a good model for this that enables this with Elipse undo / redo functionality for generated models.

Comment: You may find most of the information you're looking for on the Motivation, Core Concepts, and Three Principles pages of redux's website. https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation. Redux is not the only way to do state management, so if you don't think the reasons they describe apply to your cases, then there's no need to use redux.

Comment: I like having one immutable state tree per update. Having a stateful, class based, store that knows how to update itself has no benefits except a more terse API. Data shouldn't know how to update itself, it should just be data. You should be able to slice it with map, filter, reduce, however you want, not have magical stateful getters and setters

Comment: So for example if we simply did store.add(todo)...what is this missing?  Or store.del(todo) ... or store.filter(function) ... etc.... There has to be something that is wrong with the simplicity of these that redux adds?

Comment: Now that I understand it a little better I wonder if Redux is what is causing my browser to lockup at times when I'm writing a medium article.  I run my laptop with a lot (Possibly hundreds of Chrome tabs) open and certain I'm pushing the memory limits, so if medium runs redux and redux is trying to add reduced actions onto the stack that could cause issues ...

Comment: It also seems that we are confusing map, filter, reduce, etc. functionality with undo / redo functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is waaay too long for a comment, and may be an answer, but it's more about the concepts of why Redux exists than the nitty-gritty details of it's implementation.

Consider the deceptively simple assignment statement:

```
var foo = {bar: 1};
foo.bar = 3;
```

Simple right? Except... what if I need the previous value of `foo.bar`? What if I need to store a reference to the state transition itself so I can e.g. re-play it? Statements are not first-class entities in JavaScript:

```
var transition = foo.bar = 3;
```

isn't really meaningful. You could wrap it in a lambda expression:

```
var transition = () => { foo.bar = 3 };
```

But this fails to capture the transition semantics, where just setting the state of `foo.bar` to 3. What if the previous state matters for the next? How do you share `foo`? Stuff it in a global and hope no one mutates it on you? But if `foo` has clear semantics around it's state changes and is otherwise immutable, well...

There are some useful properties that fall out of this:

1. Code-reloading. If all of your state changes are first-class, you can reload your code and then get back to the state you were in simply by replaying them.
2. Reproducing on the server. What if production bugs dumped the state transitions that created them? Ever failed to repro a bug? Thing of the past.
3. Undo is trivial.

There are others, but you get the point. Now, you may not need all that, and it may not be worth the loss of flexibility (and Dan Abramov, author of Redux [would agree](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367)). But there is a lot to be gained by giving state transitions first-class status in your system.

Comment: Ah - OK - So could we perhaps summarize and say that Redux provides undo / redo functionality to the app?

Comment: It does seem like we could get this with a cache though ... for example store the initial state .. and each time we call todoStore.add(todo) ... push the mutated todo onto a stack that grows each time we mutate the todo ...

Comment: So the action is implicit in the API ... `add` and the store for todos could have a transactions property that records the update that was done each time the API is used ... reducer ...and if it's done like this then the developer just needs to annotate the model with a @Store annotation and use the store and will still get all the redux benefits correct?

Comment: @ole no, because you don't know *how*, only *what*... and even the what is missing some of the semantics: since `{} !== {}` how do you know if two UI states are equivalent?

Comment: I'm assuming the how is the store's method.  I added some assertions in the question, but we could have a Store interface like `Store<Todo>`.  The `Store` provides the how parts (CRUD operations).  The what is the Todo instance.  It has a unique identifier for Todo instances.  So suppose we have an array with 2 todos on it an we update one.  I think you are saying that redux helps with this since the UI state needs to be changed, but I'm not quite clear on how?

Comment: @Ole you and I keep talking past each other. You are saying "starting with these language primitives, how can I manage state?" and I'm saying "starting with these *goals* and *semantics*, how can I manage state?". *How* is not and arguably *cannot* be captured by the semantics of a method. The OO version of what I'm talking about is the Command pattern: you reify actions as a first-class entity (and it's no coincidence that Redux chose that name). The *existence* of the Command pattern is the shortest proof I can offer that you can't implement...

Comment: something like Redux as simply as I *think* you're trying to describe.

Comment: You may be right ... but I'm trying to understand it better, so if it's ok lets take it one step at a time.  If we have `@EntityStore(Todo)` indicating that we we want a store for `Todo` entities then we can construct action strings like `ADD_TODO` (For an add method), and from there construct the entire action correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178028/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-ole).

Comment: Attempted a light weight state management solution here.  It does not do immutable state at the entity level (We can patch entities), but it does broadcast changes to the store in new arrays, such that framework like angular can pickup on it via change detection.  https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice

Comment: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/storing-users-in-the-reactive-slice-object-store-5ea0fab06256

Answer (score 3):

This question seems a bit broad or opinion based but I'll give it a shot.

Redux store is immutable, because of this you cannot mutate the store. Instead Redux uses a pattern that, when given a state and action will always produce the same new state. The actions are exact that, telling the store what action to perform and the reducers execute that change and return a new state.

This may feel odd if you come from a mutable object oriented background but it allows you to walk through the state changes, go back in history and replay actions, etc. It's a powerful pattern.

Comment: Indeed I could have been a litle more specific.  So for example with the API I have outlined we could mutate the store with `addTodo(todo)`, then observers of the store could receive that update via RxJS notification or something.  So my question is really why can't the Store just implement the redux pattern for updating the store ... so that we don't need to implement anything but the store?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. But it sounds like maybe you should checkout [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)

Comment: Also looking at Akita ... https://github.com/datorama/akita     But I'm wondering if it could be simpler still ...